# Dabbles in cooking?

Tags: word-usage

I want to say someone dabbles in cooking - is it correct? -is there a better (fancy) way to say it? (this intends to add bit of humor too)

Comment: More context would be helpful here — would "spice things up" be a useful phrase in your case?

Comment: Its for a decription of my BF for a book. I am to de'scribe his personality. what i wanna say here is he tries to cook :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add a bit of wry humor, you might try a pun.  I can't think of a good pun for the verb, but you might try an adjective with a double meaning:

> He is an unseasoned cook.

From the dictionary:

> **unseasoned** (adj.)
>   1. (of food) not flavored with salt, pepper, or other spices or seasonings.
>   2. (of a person) inexperienced.

Answer (score 3):

*Dabble in* means "to be involved in something in a casual manner." So, yes you can say your boyfriend dabbles in cooking.

You could also say he plays at cooking. *Play at* means "to do something without being very serious about it." [{definition of "play at"}](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/play-at)

Comment: Or plays at being a cook.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "He's a cooking dilettante"? [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilettante) gives us:

> - An amateur, someone who dabbles in a field out of casual interest rather than as a profession or serious interest.
> - A person with a general but superficial interest in any art or a branch of knowledge. (Sometimes derogatory.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some humor, you can say:

> He *thinks* he can cook.